Identifying a function within a particular solution set for inscribed squares
I was messing around with the inscribed square problem and found a function that defines a square to be on a curve if the function equals 0 at some point representing the theta values of two points. while playing around with this, I found a quite pretty output, which I have included in a screenshot below, in the solution set of sin(5*θ) and was wondering both what the output function is, and if there are any more like it. Here is a link to the Desmos graph so you can play around with it if you would like.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/voyt9lmpnu

